# Reading text on iPad from a distance

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a regular sized 9.7" iPad. I want to be able to read text on it while running on a treadmill, from a distance of 1-2 feet.

From this distance, it is difficult to read as the text is too small. I work around it by increasing the font size. For apps like iBooks, it isn't a problem as there's a setting to adjust font size. However I usually read in a browser (usually Google Chrome or Google Search app). Unlike desktop versions, there doesn't seem to be any setting for changing font size. Google searches have led me to believe that I can change the font size in the iOS Settings app and that these apps should respect that change, but they don't appear to do so.

How do I make the font size changes to read text from a distance.

Comment: I built a custom iPad holder for my treadmill. A piece of lucite with a rim to hold iPad at bottom, and a couple holes drilled through top so as to thread rope attach to readout panel. Design will vary by exact unit, but mine works pretty well. If too complex, I think they sell gooseneck style iPad holders up to a couple feet long. You just have to figure hoe to attach to your treadmill and it'll hold your iPad stable wherever you want it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not adverse to reading articles using Safari, many websites can be viewed in **Reader Mode**.  From here you can adjust the font size along with the actual font and background color too.

[image: Reader Mode options iOS]

[image: Larger font]